# Hive Server2 is dead and pid file exists [FAILED]

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, apache-hive

I've a simple 2 node cloudera CDH5 cluster and in slave machine I've setup Hive & Hue.

I'm able to work in hive through CLI viz. creating databases and tables, I cannot configure hive/beeswax in hue and may be the reason is Hive Server2 is dead. Please help me in solving this issue.

Here are some details:

> /etc/hosts
>   192.168.1.190    master
>   192.168.1.191    slave

/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>   
<!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://master:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>master:8021</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://slave/metastore</value>
<description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>mypassword</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value>thrift://slave:9083</value>
<description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Error Logs:
/var/log/hive/hive-server2.log

> 2015-04-16 19:57:19,098 WARN  [main]: hive.metastore
>   (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(355)) - Failed to connect to the
>   MetaStore Server... 2015-04-16 19:57:20,148 WARN  [main]:
>   hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(355)) - Failed to
>   connect to the MetaStore Server... 2015-04-16 19:57:21,150 WARN 
>   [main]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(355)) - Failed
>   to connect to the MetaStore Server... 2015-04-16 19:57:22,174 WARN 
>   [main]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:startHiveServer2(112)) -
>   Error starting HiveServer2 on attempt 1, will retry in 60 seconds
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.applyAuthorizationConfigPolicy(SessionManager.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.init(CompositeService.java:59)
>     at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.init(CLIService.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.init(CompositeService.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.init(HiveServer2.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.startHiveServer2(HiveServer2.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.main(HiveServer2.java:149)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1426)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2562)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2581)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:361)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1424)
>     ... 19 more Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to
>   meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:347)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:216)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1424)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2562)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2581)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:361)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.applyAuthorizationConfigPolicy(SessionManager.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.init(CompositeService.java:59)
>     at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.init(CLIService.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.init(CompositeService.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.init(HiveServer2.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.startHiveServer2(HiveServer2.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.main(HiveServer2.java:149)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)  at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)    ... 26
>   more )    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:393)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:216)
>     ... 24 more 2015-04-16 19:58:25,074 INFO  [main]:
>   session.SessionState (SessionState.java:start(381)) - No Tez session
>   required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr. 2015-04-16
>   19:58:26,639 ERROR [Thread-6]: thrift.ThriftCLIService
>   (ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:run(115)) - Error: 
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create
>   ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.    at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.auth.HiveAuthFactory.getServerSocket(HiveAuthFactory.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftBinaryCLIService.run(ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:89)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

THANK YOU SO MUCH :-)

Comment: Port `10000` might be in use. Try this `hive --service hiveserver2 -p 10001`.

Comment: And use the 'beeline' command, not 'hive' if you want to use Hive through HiveServer2 and debug it.